# React onChange on radio button fires onClick on parent div element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to handle changes by keyboard differently from changes by mouse clicks. For this purpose I have created following component. My problem is, that when I use the arrow keys and space to select the radio button, it uses the onClick method from the parent div element before it uses the onChange method from the input element. What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I handle it correctly?

```js
class Radio extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    this.state = { checked: false };
  }

  onChange() {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
    console.log('onChange');
  }

  onClick() {
    this.onChange();
    console.log('onClick');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          checked={this.state.checked}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        Click me!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Radio />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen in [**this issue**](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7407) and this part of the [**W3C documentation**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/content-models.html#interactive-content), this seems to be a default browser behavior.

> When the user triggers an element with a defined activation behavior in a manner other than clicking it, the default action of the interaction event must be to run synthetic click activation steps on the element.

To work around this, add the following logic in your `onClick` handler:

```
if (e.type === 'click' && e.clientX !== 0 && e.clientY !== 0) {
  // This is a real click. Do something here
}
```

<sup>Creds to GitHub user [Ro Savage](https://github.com/ro-savage), for pointing this out.</sup>

---

Here's a full demo for you:

```js
class Radio extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    this.state = { checked: false };
  }

  onChange() {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
    console.log('onChange');
  }

  onClick(e) {
    if (e.type === 'click' && e.clientX !== 0 && e.clientY !== 0) {
      this.onChange();
      console.log('onClick');
    } else {
      console.log('prevented "onClick" on keypress');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          checked={this.state.checked}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        Click me!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Radio />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very interesting! Your solution works great, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the propagation of the click event:

```
<input
    type="radio"
    checked={this.state.checked}
    onClick={(e)=>{e.stopPropagation()}}
    onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem with this solution is, that the radio button doesn't get checked visually, when using the keyboard. Is there any option to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The order of events matters: the click event will fire before the change event.
Because events bubble up, the `onClick`-handler of the parent elements will get triggered before the `onChange`-handler of the child-element.

To fix your specific issue, you could for example listen to the `keydown`-event on the container-div. This event should get triggered before click- or change-events.

```js
class Radio extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onKeyUp = this.onKeyUp.bind(this);

    this.state = { checked: false };
  }

  onChange() {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
    console.log('onChange');
  }

  onKeyUp() {
    console.log('onKeyUp');
    this.onChange();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          checked={this.state.checked}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        Click me!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Radio />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```